# ISO 8583 server bitmap is -1

Tags: bitmap, iso8583, jpos

I use JPOS to send and receive ISO 8583 messages. 
Here is Client :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ISOException {
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
    EvnMsg msg = new EvnMsg();
    ISO93APackager packager = new ISO93APackager(); 
    msg.setPackager(packager);
    msg.setMTI("1804");
    msg.setAuditNumber("124125");
    ASCIIChannel channel  = new ASCIIChannel("Server_IP", PORT, packager);
    channel.connect();
    channel.send(msg);
    channel.receive();
    //channel.disconnect();
}
```

Here is Server :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ISOException {
    ISO93APackager packager = new ISO93APackager();
    ServerChannel channel = new ASCIIChannel (packager);
    channel.accept(new ServerSocket(PORT));
    ISOMsg isoMsg = channel.receive();

    System.out.println("Received");
}
```

Server is received message, but the problem is that the bitmap has value of -1

[image]

So did i made a mistake? Which is the right way to receive the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an internal representation used by jPOS, feel free to ignore that fact; the bitmap will be properly produced once the channel calls the ISOMsg's `pack()` method.

A few comments:

- `EnvMsg` is not part of jPOS, I'm assuming you're extending `ISOMsg`
- You don't have to call `msg.setPackager`, the channel will take care of that on your behalf
- You're reinventing the wheel in your server by not using the `QServer` class
- You're reinventing the wheel in your client code by not using the `ChannelAdaptor` class
- You'll probably need a multiplexer, consider using `QMUX`
- I suggest you take a look at the Q2 application to run all this.

Comment: Thank you @apr. It's good if you have some information or example about ChannelAdaptor or Q2.

Comment: Please take a look at http://jpos.org/learn, there's a free guide with plenty information about Q2 and the ChannelAdaptor.